# MUI: A component is changing the default value state of an uncontrolled Rating after being initialized

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

What is the problem, why does such an error occur: MUI: A component is changing the default value state of an uncontrolled Rating after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled Rating.

```
const StarsRating = (props) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Stack spacing={1}>
                <Rating name="half-rating"
                        defaultValue={props.vote_average
                            ? Math.round(props.vote_average / 2)
                            : 0}
                        sx={{
                            '& .MuiRating-iconFilled': {
                                color: '#544C21',
                            },
                            '& .MuiRating-iconFocus': {
                                color: 'orange',
                            },
                            '& .MuiRating-iconHover': {
                                color: 'green',
                            }
                        }}/>
            </Stack>
        </>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix the console warning, you'll need to switch `defaultValue` to use `value`. I was having a similar problem and found the answer here: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/8zuwek/warning_a_component_is_changing_an_uncontrolled/
"React will not show that warning if a value prop is provided"...

So if you change

```
<Rating name="half-rating"
     defaultValue={props.vote_average
         ? Math.round(props.vote_average / 2)
         : 0}
     sx={{
         '& .MuiRating-iconFilled': {
            color: '#544C21',
         },
         '& .MuiRating-iconFocus': {
             color: 'orange',
         },
         '& .MuiRating-iconHover': {
             color: 'green',
         }
}}/>
```

to

```
<Rating name="half-rating"
     value={props.vote_average
         ? Math.round(props.vote_average / 2)
         : 0}
     sx={{
         '& .MuiRating-iconFilled': {
            color: '#544C21',
         },
         '& .MuiRating-iconFocus': {
             color: 'orange',
         },
         '& .MuiRating-iconHover': {
             color: 'green',
         }
}}/>
```

the error will go away.